# How to run your JUnit tests on two different databases

Tags: java, junit, annotations, junit4

I want to run the same Tests using two different @ContextConfiguration

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/test/oracle.xml")
public class OracleTest extends BaseTest {}
```

Having also a similar copy for the other database I can run all Tests in the abstract class BaseTest for each database. This method has two drawbacks:

1. I have triple the number of classes
2. I can only execute tests in the base class by going to the OracleTest class and execute all tests

Is there a better way to do this? I tried several annotations (@ContextHierarchy, @Transactional et al.) but as I never used them before I don't really understand what they are doing. One possibility seems to be DbUnit, but I don't know how this could really help.

Comment: Well, I think that you don't really have any other choice tbh. Your solution is not bad anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Number of unit test classes concerns me much less than using test Spring contexts.
I consider tests Spring context as anti-pattern. Your integration test isn't testing production wiring. Thus your production context stays un-tested. Try to avoid creation of test contexts and rather use production Spring configuration in your integration tests.

You have to have some mechanism for replacing DB configuration in production (e.g. placeholders). Try to extract that DB configuration into separate file (e.g. db.properties). If you do that, you can replace db.properties on test classpath and use production Spring context for testing.